# Connecting to Postgres database using C++

Tags: c++, postgresql

I am trying to connect to a Postgres database on a Red Hat Linux server from my Windows desktop. I have "Postgres DB ODBC Driver 9.0.0" installed on my Windows machine. I am using the following code. The connection is unsuccessful. I am wondering if my headers are alright and if my _szDSN string is alright?

I used a very similar code to connect successfully to a local Access database that I created on my desktop. I also have "Microsoft Access database engine 2010" installed on my desktop.

Please let me know if more information is necessary to answer this question. Thanks for help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

int main()
{
    SQLHENV env;
    SQLHDBC dbc;
    SQLHSTMT stmt;
    SQLRETURN rc;

    //*** Connecting to remote PostgreSQL database
    rc = SQLAllocEnv( &env );
    rc = SQLAllocConnect( env, &dbc );
    if( SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc) )
    {
        std::cout << "allocation successful" << std::endl;
    }
    std::string _szDSN = "DATABASE=dbname; SERVER=123.45.66.7; PORT=5432; UID=id123; PWD=pw123;";
    rc = SQLDriverConnect( dbc, NULL, (unsigned char*)(_szDSN.c_str()), SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT );
    if( SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc) )
    {
        std::cout << "Connection successful" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Connection UNsuccessful" << std::endl;
    }


    //*** Exit program
    std::cout.flush();
    std::getchar();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: The first thing to check is whether your Postgres server on your Linux machine is listening on port 5432 at all. Check [`pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

Comment: The server administrator confirmed that pg_hba.conf is correctly set up and listening on port 5432. I did a netstat and got the following. 

    $ netstat -na | grep 5432  tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:5432  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN        
    tcp   0   0 :::5432 :::*     LISTEN        
    unix  2   [ ACC ]   STREAM   LISTENING    258994343 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of the ODBC driver? Also, please show output from commands as edits to the question, not comments, as they're much more legible that way.

Comment: Well ... what's the error reported through ODBC by psqlODBC? Use the ODBC APIs to get the error message and have your program print it out. It'll probably be quite informative.